# Piezoelectric powder solution to measure extremely high pressure

Tags: pressure, sensor, piezoelectric

**Idea -** While reading about piezoelectric materials, I thought about mixing piezoelectric powder with silicon oil to measure extremely high pressures (of up to 4000bar).

**Experiment -** Consider a cylindrical container containing the "Si + Piezo powder" mixture.

[image: Mixture container]

When an extremely high pressure, say 4000 bar, is applied from the top as shown, the solution would act as a solid. If there are enough piezo particles in the solution, then

1) would this solution act as a piezoelectric solid?

2) When yes, how can I measure the current generated in the solution?

3) could you also suggest some conceptual ideas or designs to measure pressure (up to 4000 bar) through the solution mentioned above. I am trying to measure the pressure without using any physical sensor (piezoelectric sensor, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) would this solution act as a piezoelectric solid?

It would not. Although crystals in each individual particle have piezoelectric properties, their dipole moments are randomly oriented and, therefore, would not produce any net voltage under pressure.

To make a sensor, PZT powder has to be converted (through a series of steps) into a solid part (e.g., a disc with metallic contacts on the top and bottom surfaces) and polarized (poled) by the application of high DC voltage. As a result of poling, randomly oriented dipoles get aligned and will respond to the applied pressure by generating voltage between the contacts.

I don't see any practical way of sensing pressure by just mixing the powder with oil.